# What's the correct way to do this <Image Source="../Images/{Binding Path=Id}.jpg"/>?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have an Employee ID and an image associated with that employee in as a resource in the project (the image is being shown in a list next to employees name).

So I think something like this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Employee}">
        <Grid>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="image" Source="../Images/{Binding Path=Id}.jpg"/>
```

It's not valid XAML.

I suppose I could handle some databinding event in the codebehind and create the path there?  Doesn't seem ideal to me.

I could store the path in my Employee class but that's terrible.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to keep it all xaml...

Comment: If you want to keep it all in XAML, you have to use DataTriggers based on the Id value. `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="1"><Setter Property="Source" TargetName="Image" Value="../Images/1.jpg"/></DataTrigger>`. Also, use PNGs instead, which support transparency.

Comment: Your scenario is exactly what binding converters were made for.

Comment: Late to the conversation but I don't think one should *ever* opt for XAML for the sake of doing everything in XAML. Value converters were created for this purpose. The next best thing is to implement custom markup extensions which allow you to use custom logic in markup - but you are still falling back on C# code somewhere. Trying too hard to keep it XAML inevitably leads to unnecessary & messy markup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to use a `IValueConverter`

Heres a simple example passing in a `String.Format` as the converter paramerter

```
public class StringFormatToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter is string)
        {
            return string.Format(parameter.ToString(), value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<XXXX.Resources>
    <local:StringFormatToImageSourceConverter x:Key="StringToImage" />
</XXXX.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding Path=Id, Converter={StaticResource StringToImage}
     , ConverterParameter=../Images/{0}.jpg}" />
```

There is a way to keep it all in `Xaml` by using an invisible `TextBlock` to format the string, but not the best practice.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="StringToImage" Visibility="Hidden" Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat=../Images/{0}.jpg}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=StringToImage}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hoped that the `StringFormat` work directly on the main Binding, but it seems to work only when the target property is of type `string`.
+1 for the fun alternative with hidden text, even if I'll never use it ;)

Comment: I used this converter solution.  I would like to know why the hidden textblock is not best practice.  I am new to WPF and it would be great to hear why not to do things like this.  Thanks.