# Use StringFormat to add a string to a WPF XAML binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, string-formatting

I have a WPF 4 application that contains a TextBlock which has a one-way binding to an integer value (in this case, a temperature in degrees Celsius).  The XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockTemperature">
        <Run Text="{Binding CelsiusTemp, Mode=OneWay}"/></TextBlock>
```

This works fine for displaying the actual temperature value but I'd like to format this value so it includes °C instead of just the number (30°C instead of just 30).  I've been reading about StringFormat and I've seen several generic examples like this:

```
// format the bound value as a currency
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
```

and

```
// preface the bound value with a string and format it as a currency
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=Amount: {0:C}}"/>
```

Unfortunately, none of the examples I've seen have appended a string to the bound value as I'm trying to do.  I'm sure it's got to be something simple but I'm not having any luck finding it.  Can anyone explain to me how to do that?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Your first example is effectively what you need:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CelsiusTemp, StringFormat={}{0}°C}" />
```

Comment: Why does the string format in xaml have the leading empty `{}`?

Comment: @Jonesopolis It's in the docs - but if your format string starts with a `{`, it provides a mechanism to escape, since `{}` already has meaning in xaml.

Comment: could you link to the docs for xaml string formatting. I cannot find them.

Comment: @Eric https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I do not see where the documentation explains the leading {}.

Comment: @Eric Like much documentation, it stinks - they demo it, but don't explain.

Comment: oh well, I had seen that page before and was hoping you knew of something better.

Comment: Trying to do this in XAML in a Windows 10 Universal app, and it complains that there is no `StringFormat` property.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 This answer was for WPF (as tagged in the question), not UWP.

Comment: @ReedCopsey XAML was tagged in the question (which is the root technology at play here) and is not technically specific to WPF or UWP. -- Databinding is a core feature of XAML (core features are supposed to work the same even when using it just for plain-jane object graphs, and neither UWP or WPF is involved, etc.) -- anyway, I wasn't complaining, just calling it out as a caveat for others who may be in the same boat.

Comment: here the documentation of the mysterious {}:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx

Comment: There is a StringFormat property in Xamarin Forms

Comment: So this comes up as a top hit while I am searching for Xamarin info. At least in that flavor of XAML you can do <Label Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat='Amount: {0:C}'}"/>   (note the single quotes)

Comment: you just need {} when the format string starts with the parameter {0}, it is not needed if the format string starts with a text. ex: "{}{0} + {1}" "Page {0} of {1}". Credit to [Dakianth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456496/dakianth)

Answer (score 144):

Please note that using [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat) property in Bindings only seems to work for "text" properties. [Using this for Label.Content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209539/3195477) will not work

Comment: A **VERY** important point that took me trying it until I got desperate and found this comment to validate my suspicion.

Comment: `ContentStringFormat` comes to the rescue, example: `Content="{Binding Path=TargetProjects.Count}" ContentStringFormat="Projects: {0}"`.

Comment: Thanks Casper, real hero for posting that info.

Comment: for GridViewColumn headers, use `HeaderStringFormat="{}{0} For Report"`

Comment: If you're using design time data it seems you need to rebuild the project after editing ContentStringFormat to get changes to reflect in the designer, whereas StringFormat as used on say a text box will update the designer in realtime.

Comment: For Image's Source see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15580855/6131611)

Comment: This **heroic** answer has made it possible to waste **less than ~5 minutes** before understanding what was going wrong with this. Casper and @astrowalker, you are still saving people's time, year after year! Kudos!

Comment: And people keep asking why I love WPF so much.

Comment: For databinding Header property of `System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox` also use `HeaderStringFormat`

Comment: You can override the headers and components of controls like GroupBox that use Label to use TextBlock instead. That way you can still use StringFormat.

Answer (score 140):

Here's an alternative that works well for readability if you have the Binding in the middle of the string or multiple bindings:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="Temperature is "/>
  <Run Text="{Binding CelsiusTemp}"/>
  <Run Text="°C"/>  
</TextBlock>

<!-- displays: 0°C (32°F)-->
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{Binding CelsiusTemp}"/>
  <Run Text="°C"/>
  <Run Text=" ("/>
  <Run Text="{Binding Fahrenheit}"/>
  <Run Text="°F)"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I like this answer a little better because I can insert text from a string library easily.  Of course if you're really worried about internationalization, you'd probably be better off using a converter so the order of the number and units isn't fixed.

<Run Text="{x:Static s:UIStrings.General_FahrenheitAbbreviation}" />

Comment: This is a great solution, but I am getting extra spaces in the final text display, between the Text Runs - any idea why? In your example I see ``0 °C  ( 32 °F)``

Comment: It's not super useful if you want to do actual string formatting (i.e. control the number of decimal places, etc.).

Comment: @Conrad If you don't want the spaces between each run, you should put those runs on a single line as follows:


<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{Binding CelsiusTemp}"/><Run Text="°C"/><Run Text=" ("/:<Run Text="{Binding Fahrenheit}"/><Run Text="°F)"/>
</TextBlock>

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 That's what you'd use a ValueConverter for, I think

Answer (score -17):

In xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CelsiusTemp}" />
```

In `ViewModel`, this way setting the value also works:

```
 public string CelsiusTemp
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0}°C", _CelsiusTemp); }
            set
            {
                value = value.Replace("°C", "");
              _CelsiusTemp = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This goes against the whole point of View-Viewmodel separation

Comment: Sometimes a "hack" is the way to go, why not?

Comment: This does not have to be always "hack". It is OK to provide formatted text in ViewModel and display it in several places in View (View is then less bulky). And the role of ViewModel is to separate View from Model in MVVM, isn't it?

Comment: How to represent the data depends on the View, not the ViewModel. Moreover, the setter that replaces text looks awful - the dirtiest hack I've ever seen.