# TextBlock Using A C# Style String.Format For Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, string.format

C# has a function String.Format(string, arguments[]) which works like the following.

```
String.Format("here's my argument {0}", 1337)
```

This would return the string "here's my argument 1337". With the TextBlock object I'm having trouble getting functionality like this. I would like to do something like

```
<TextBlock Text=String.Format("here's my argument {0}", {Binding Argument})/>
```

Where it's taking a binding as an input but I can't seem to find any way to do this with a single TextBlock. Is there a similar object type which could handle this or is there some way to pull this off with text blocks?

Comment: isn't this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278515/use-stringformat-to-add-a-string-to-a-wpf-xaml-binding this question?

Comment: How many parameters you want to use in the format string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) for that

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Argument, StringFormat=here\'s my argument {0}}"/>
```