# Concatenate string via XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, concatenation, string.format

I have this label inside `ProgressBar` that take it's value form the `Progressbar` value and i want to add the char `%` after the `ProgressBar` value.

I have tried two options that not working:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Progress}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} %" />
<Label Content="{Binding Progress, StringFormat={}{0}%}" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use StringFormat to add a string to a WPF XAML binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278515/use-stringformat-to-add-a-string-to-a-wpf-xaml-binding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TextBlock` instead.

```
<ProgressBar Value="50" Name="prog" ... />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=prog, StringFormat={}{0}%}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

e.g. with [ContentStringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Progress}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} %" />
```

or you use [Standard Numeric Format Specifier P](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString)

```
ContentStringFormat="{}{0:P}"
```

This all is very similar to `String.Format`.

Comment: On my case, I needed concatenate a Binding variable with a static String. Worked perfectly with this code!